# Asp.net URL Rewriting

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting

I would like to use the ASP.Net URL Rewriting to achieve the following:

My application is physically hosted in the IIS at the following end point: http://www.example.com/someIISApplication/Default.aspx

I want the user to make a request with the following URL and hit the above end point with a querystring parameter like this:

Requested from browser: http://www.example.com/ABC/someIISApplication/Default.aspx

This is how it actually hits the ASP.Net after route processing: http://www.example.com/someIISApplication/Default.aspx?MyParam=ABC

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [URL Rewrite Module for IIS](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) .

Create **redirect** rule on the **site level** (www.example.com)

Pattern: **^([_0-9a-z-]+)/someIISApplication/Default.aspx**

Redirect URL: **someIISApplication/Default.aspx?MyParam={R:1}**

For more details see ["Creating Rewrite Rules for the URL Rewrite Module"](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module)

Comment: Yes i have Achieved this with URL Re Writing. thanks for the reply.